# Regular Expression to remove annotation code

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex.

I try to remove unused code in project like

```
/*
    // random unmanaged annotation
    foo = var;
    doSomething();
    multilineFunction(a,
                      b);
*/
```

and leave "not code" annotation

```
/*
     real annotation
*/
```

I try to find and replace with regular expresion that "inside between /* and */ contains line endwith ;" but It's doesn't work with my regex. How  make that regex?

I tried inside of /* */ by `(/\*)(.*\n)*?(.*\*/)`, and **cotains line endswith ;** `(/\*)(.*\n)*?(.*;\n)(.*\n)(.*\*/)` but this regex find last match of */ and maybe dirty.

**Edit**: I wanted to do this only as replacement function in IDE. I solved it now by writing python code, but I'm still curious.

Comment: How do you differentiate between "code" and "not code"?

Comment: @Sweeper I assumed it was not a code comment if there was no semicolon inside the comment.

Comment: Regex is fundamentally the wrong tool for this. The following is about HTML but the fundamental reasoning is the same for any context-free language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @tripleee this is good but can't filter contains semicolone.

Comment: I would go with something like https://github.com/eliben/pycparser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, it is better to use a good parser.

For a one-time hack, you can use the following regex:

```
\/\*[^;]*;.*?\*\/
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/e5tOEB/1).

Assumptions for it to work without issues:
- the code is proper C and it contains semi-colons `;`
- the annotations do NOT contain semi-colons `;`.

If the assumptions are not fulfilled, you need to do some additional hacks, or to use a proper parser, as stated initially.

Comment: this is not work for my IDE(Rider) but work find in Test.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\/\*\s+(\/\/.+)[\s\S]+\*\/`

Explanation:

`\/\*` - match `\*` literally

`\s+` - match one or more whitespaces (including newline character)

`(\/\/.+)` - match line beginning with `\\`, i.e. comment (but only one line) and store it in first capturing group

`[\s\S]+` - match one or more of any characters (`\s` is whitespace and `\S` is non-whitespace

`\*\/` - match `*\` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KNaixC/1)

Then replace it with first capturig group.

Note that it will only work with one ilne comments placed at the beginnng if a commented block